# Dual Sim not work in Android mobile when use 3G internet

Tags: android

I have a android phone with dual sim. One sim use for 3G internet connection. other for call. But problem is that. When I using internet that time if anyone call me to other sim they can't get me. the other sim say not available. when I stop internet use then other sim will available.

My android version is 4.0.4

Comment: This is not a programming question. Pleas try [android.se] instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your android mobile go to **setting** then **sim card manager** then select 
**Receive incomming calls** (via other sim card while using data service)..
but after this this setting causes slower transmission..